# CSS - how to place a background-image on my background?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to display some random design images on my sites background as background-image, problem now is that every time I place such an image it somehow interacts with nearby boxes etc.
I just want my design images (small icons etc) to be part of the background without getting in touch with other non-design elements like text, boxes etc.

Something like that I guess:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url("/static/pattern.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: -10;
} -> "The actual background of the site"

.design_element_01 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url("/static/xyz.png");
    max-width: 100px;
} -> "The design element that should get placed onto the body background from above"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```css
.design_element_01 {
  position: absolute
  /*...*/
}
```

In addition, you might need to change `max-width` to `width`, since a `background` doesn't provide width to the element.

---

### Centering the Background

There are a few different approaches to centering the background. I'll outline one here; if it doesn't work for you, I can describe others.

Essentially, the idea is to make the `.design_element_01` element *itself* take up the entire page. Then, `background-size` can be used to constrain the size of the *background*, and `background-position` can be used to center it. A basic example would be:

```
.design_element_01 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("/static/xyz.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* I'm using 100px here since you used max-width: 100px, but you can use whatever you want. */
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

*(Do note that I haven't tested this; you may need to tweak it.)*

If you test this example, however, you will notice that this centers the background on the *screen*, but not necessarily the entire page. This may or may not be what you want. If not, you can change the `<body>` element's position property:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

This should cause the `.design_element_01` element to be positioned relative to the `<body>` element.

I also created a JSFiddle example to demonstrate the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mouqewzv/.

Finally, if you don't want your element *completely* centered, but just offset from the center, you could tweak the `left` and `top` properties of `design_element_01` to position the background *initially* at the center, but then offset it.

Comment: Can I actually make it that way that the icon(s) are right next to my boxes and not somewhere in the free wild 100 meters left or right? Somehow i need a "alignment from center"

Comment: @MarkusBrede I added information for *centering* the background. However, reading back through your comment, I'm thinking that's not quite what you're looking for. Could you maybe edit your question and provide more detail/examples describing what *exactly* your looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your design_element_01 position to absolute NOT relative
and then try to place it however you want using
left:
right:
top:
bottom:
z-index:

Hope this works!